# Choose the number of kernels used by ParallelTable

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization, kernel, kernel-startup

By default, on my system, `ParallelTable` uses 4 kernels. Is it possible to change the number of kernels used, for example using only 3 instead of 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can launch as many or as few kernels as you like, see [`LaunchKernels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaunchKernels.html) and [`CloseKernels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloseKernels.html). Parallel functions will use as many as are currently running.

E.g., `LaunchKernels[3]` would launch 3 additional kernels. Before you run any parallel commands, simply launch precisely as many as you need. Then automatic launching won't be triggered anymore.

If you already launched too many, use `CloseKernels` to close as many as you don't need.

Answer (score 9):

Another way from the menu (if accessible): Edit $ \rightarrow $ Preferences $ \rightarrow $ Parallel $ \rightarrow $ Local Kernels $ \rightarrow $ (Number of local kernels to use) Manual setting